# Best way to calculate the midpoint of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, binary-search

I've noticed that people use different ways to calculate the mid point of an ordered array and its sub arrays.  This is often used in binary search.

The first method seems a bit better as it is simpler.  Does the second way offer any advantages?

```
const mid = Math.round((left + right) / 2);
```

and

```
const mid = left + Math.round((right - left) / 2);
```

and ( per answer )

```
const mid =  ( left + right ) >>> 1;
```

Comment: Second might be less susceptible to overflow.

Comment: @ScottHunter not for JavaScript arrays, since they cannot be longer than 2^32, while JavaScript can exactly represent integers up to 2^53-1.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think that `Math.round` is what you will find more often, because it will round upwards any integer + 0.5. E.g., `Math.round(3.5) === 4`. This is not the most common way to find the integer midpoint. The main reason is that alternative ways involving integers (as opposed to floating point numbers), all round downwards:

- `(left + right) >>> 1` (`>>>` is the unsigned right shift)
- `~~((left + right) * 0.5)` (`~~` is a way to cast to integer)
- in other languages: integer division by 2 of `left + right`

These ways that involve integers are probably faster than calling `Math.round()`, check it on your browser. Furthermore, JavaScript is an exception among languages, in that it doesn't differentiate, except within operations, between integers and floats. Most languages will explicitly use integers for array indices, and so the right shift above is for them obviously the fastest way to divide by 2. This has also influenced the literature, so you will find `⌊(left+right)/2⌋` much more often than `⌈(left+right)/2⌉`.
If you insist on using the `Math` library, this means using `Math.floor((left + right) / 2)`.

The only reason not to use integer operations could be that integers are [signed 32 bit integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)) in JavaScript, while floats are 64 bit [IEEE 754 floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), which have [53 significant bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (including an implied `1` bit). If your array indices can exceed `2147483637` (2<sup>31</sup>-1), you cannot use integer operations. This situation is unlikely, though, also because the size of JavaScript arrays cannot exceed `4294967296` (2<sup>32</sup>) anyway.

As for your question, the second form is not only a bit longer on screen, it also implies one more math operation. The second form *would* have an advantage over the first if indices could get close to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is `9007199254740991` (2<sup>53</sup>-1) (because the subtraction would allow indices to be closer to that limit), but as we have seen this is not possible for JavaScript arrays.

Comment: but `i / 2` is not an integer division, in JavaScript. You still have to take the floor of that.

Comment: mind you, `>>> 2` is an integer division by `4`, the division by `2` is `>>> 1`. Anyway, I don't know what Node does under the hood, but if I were a Node developer, I would keep the integer representation of a variable around, once it has been calculated, in order not to have to convert the representation back and forth. And a time when the integer representation is needed (unsigned, in this case, but that makes almost no difference), is when a variable is used as an index into an array.

Comment: sorry ... typo ... from your answer it seems ( i >>> 1 ) is the preferred method to divide by 2, this involves no floating point math, and particularly preferred if you don't have to worry about overflow, which in this case one does not.

Comment: you can even have an overflow when adding two indices close to 2^32-1, but when you right shift unsigned the overflowed sum, the result is correct. You just don't have to look at the sum before shifting it, because it would appear to be negative. But as an unsigned integer it's correct.

Comment: what I wrote above can be checked like this: `m=2**31-1; n=m-2 `, then `(m+n)>>>1 == m-1` and `(m+n)>>1 == -2` are both `true`